# How to Copy formats across sheets in excel

Tags: excel

I have two sheets:

[image]

[image]

They both have the same values. However, sheet1 has different number formats. Is there a way to apply all these to all columns in sheet2 apart from manually going one by one and changing the number format. This becomes unbearable once the number of columns grows.

Comment: I would set up a template with all the formats specified then you always have the same starting point. If copy/ pasting then paste.special values.

Answer (score 0):

1- Select the cell with the formatting you want to copy.

2- Select Home > Format Painter.

3- Drag to select the cell or range you want to apply the formatting to.

4- Release the mouse button and the formatting should now be applied.